# Laravel Eloquent split large query in to chunk and reuse it

Tags: php, laravel, reusability, code-reuse, laravel-5.6

I am having really a very big query formation like below. i want to split this and need to re-use for many other ajax call's

```
$buildquery=Hotel::has('room');

        $buildquery->whereHas('room', function($query) use ($request) {

            // If amenities is there add it to query
            if($request->filled('amenities')){
                $amenities = $request->amenities;
                $count = count($amenities);

                $query->withCount(['amenities' => function($query) use ($amenities, $count){
                                $query->whereIn('amenities_id', $amenities);
                            }])
                            ->having('amenities_count', $count);
                }

                /* filter based on guest */

                if($request->filled('guestsCount')){
                    $memberCount = $request->guestsCount + $request->childCount;
                    $query->Where('capacity', '>=',  $memberCount);
                }else{
                    $query->Where('capacity', '>=',  1);
                }
        });

        $buildquery->with(['room' => function ($query) use ($request) {

            // If amenities is there add it to query
            if($request->filled('amenities')){
                $amenities = $request->amenities;
                $count = count($amenities);

                $query->withCount(['amenities' => function($query) use ($amenities, $count){
                                $query->whereIn('amenities_id', $amenities);
                            }])
                            ->having('amenities_count', $count);
                }

            /* filter based on guest */

            if($request->filled('guestsCount')){
                $memberCount = $request->guestsCount + $request->childCount;
                $query->Where('capacity', '>=',  $memberCount);
            }else{
                $query->Where('capacity', '>=',  1);
            }

            $query->with('roomtype')->with('floorroomcount')->with('image')->with('amenities');

            $query->OrderBy('price');
            $query->Where('astatus', 1)->Where('status', 0);
        }]);


        /* client must be active */
        $buildquery->whereHas('client', function($query) {
            $query->Where('status', 1);
        });

        /* search based on rating */
        if ($request->filled('rating')) {
            if($request->rating > 0){
                $rating = $request->rating;
                    $buildquery->where('star', $rating);
            }
        }

        /* search based on hotel */
        if ($request->filled('location_id')) {
            $buildquery->Where('city', $request->location_id);
        }

        @include('roomlist.area');

       $buildquery->Where('astatus', 1)->where('status', 0); //actually its hotel

       $hotels = $buildquery->simplePaginate(20);

       $hotels = $this->addRates($hotels, $request->checkin_date, $request->checkout_date);
       $hotels = $this->addAvailableCount($hotels, $request->checkin_date, $request->checkout_date);

        $hotels = $hotels->transform(function (Hotel $hotel){

            $hotel->setRelation('room', $hotel->room->sortBy('price')->flatten());

            return $hotel;
        });

        return view('roomlist.loadmore', compact('hotels'));
```

please see this line `@include('roomlist.area');` in that `roomlist/area.blade.php` file i am having the following code

```
<?php
    if($request->filled('type')){
        if($request->type == "Area"){

            //get the area first
            $hotel = Hotel::select('area')->where('city', $request->location_id)->first();
            if(isset($hotel)){
                if($hotel->area != null){
                    $buildquery->where('area', $hotel->area);
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Is there any way that i can include this code from a blade or in any other manner.

Note: i need to re-use many things like this.

Comment: yes make a blade file and use it every where you want in blade add your code inside `@section("example")` and every where you want to use it put `@yield("example")` inside

Comment: @Babak the first query is inside a controller

Comment: for that make a function in helper and call it every where you want ether controller or blade

Comment: i am using many variables from the `request`, so i think helper wont help

Comment: well you can add a code like this at top of your codes `$request = request();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you could do is break some of this functionality into scopes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes

For instance, you could change this:

```
    /* search based on hotel */
    if ($request->filled('location_id')) {
        $buildquery->Where('city', $request->location_id);
    }
```

Into this:

```
if ($request->filled('location_id')) {
   $buildquery->inCity($request->location_id);
}
```

Or this:

```
    /* client must be active */
    $buildquery->whereHas('client', function($query) {
        $query->Where('status', 1);
    });
```

into this:

```
$buildquery->withActiveClient();
```

This is a small change but it allows you to use `inCity` in other places without re-writing as much, and for the other scopes it might be more code you can extract.

You could also make a Transformer class to change this:

```
    $hotels = $hotels->transform(function (Hotel $hotel){

        $hotel->setRelation('room', $hotel->room->sortBy('price')->flatten());

        return $hotel;
    });
```

To this:

```
    $hotels = (new HotelRoomTransformer())->transform($hotels);
```

This type of extracting code could make this file much more readable, and that way if you need to reuse parts of it you have them in separate, reusable files.

Lastly, this type of functionality can all be extracted into a repository if you want to entirely remove Eloquent from your controllers.  Here is a short guide on the repository pattern: https://medium.com/@connorleech/use-the-repository-design-pattern-in-a-laravel-application-13f0b46a3dce